# Show document icon in jqGrid Column Headers

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a property in jqgrid which I can set for all the columns of the grid to have a document icon next to the columns?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid do you use?

Comment: jqGrid.Core(2.2)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.